# Scheduling the Storing of BO Reports in PDF Format

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible in BusinessObjects 4.0/4.1 to do the following:

- Create a report in PDF format
- Transfer and store the report on some Windows Share folder
- Schedule this process

It this is possible, can anyone give short guidelines on how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's basic scheduling functionality.

From Launchpad, right-click on the report and hit "Schedule".

Click the recurrence tab to set the scheduling recurrence.

Click the Formats tab and select Acrobat.

Click the Destinations tab and select File System.

One important note on Destinations -- you can optionally enter the Windows user name and password that will be used to connect to the file share when the report is generated.  You can leave this blank, in which case the BO server will connect to the file share **as the account that BO runs as** (that is, the user name that the SIA service runs as).  In this case, the service account must have r/w permission to the file share.  On the other hand, if you enter credentials manually, you need to make sure that any recurring schedules get updated if/when you change the accounts password, else the account will quickly get locked out (I know from experience....)

For more info, click the Help menu in Launchpad, then review the section on *Scheduling Objects*.